# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod issue and Need to determine Heap Memory

Tags: java, powershell, tomcat

Using the code at: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3iced0/gettomcat_status/

If we invoke the following URL: http://RemoteServer/manager/status?XML=true

We see below for Heap Memory:

- Name:PS Eden Space
- Name:PS Old Gen
- Name:PS Survivor Space

The problem I am having is adding all three of these for Used and Maximum seems to be way off (way too high).

with each having Heap Memory.  Does this mean that Heap memory is additive or includes all three of these?

```
Memory Pools
Name:PS Eden Space Type:Heap memory Initial:1210056704 Committed:1155530752 Maximum:1168113664 Used:984427608 
Name:PS Old Gen Type:Heap memory Initial:538968064 Committed:538968064 Maximum:538968064 Used:507145336 
Name:PS Survivor Space Type:Heap memory Initial:199229440 Committed:226492416 Maximum:226492416 Used:0
```

Let's show some code:

```
function Get-TomcatStatus{
     param(
     $fileName,
         $tomcatserver ,
         $tomcatport = 80,
         $tomcatuser = "login",
         $tomcatpassword = "pass"
     )
     # https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3iced0/gettomcat_status/
     #Get Credentials into the right format
     $tomcatpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $tomcatpassword -asplaintext -force
     $cred = New-object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ($tomcatuser,$tomcatpassword)

     #Invoke the restinterface 
     Write-Host http://$tomcatserver`:$tomcatport/manager/status?XML=true
     $TomcatStats = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://$tomcatserver`:$tomcatport/manager/status?XML=true -Credential $cred

     # <threadInfo  maxThreads="150" currentThreadCount="25" currentThreadsBusy="1" />
     $threads = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("threadInfo") | ? {$_.currentThreadCount -ne 0}

     $Memory = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memory") 

     # <memorypool name='PS Eden Space' type='Heap memory' usageInit='1210056704' usageCommitted='1155530752' usageMax='1168113664' usageUsed='1027265568'/>
     $MemoryEden = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memorypool") | ? {$_.name -eq "PS Eden Space"}
     $MemoryOldGen = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memorypool") | ? {$_.name -eq "PS Old Gen"}
     $MemorySurvivor = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memorypool") | ? {$_.name -eq "PS Survivor Space"}

     # <requestInfo  maxTime="6302" processingTime="32729" requestCount="260" errorCount="215" bytesReceived="61985" bytesSent="162507" />
     $requestInfo = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("requestInfo") | ? {$_.bytessent -ne 0}

     #Populate output object
     #$Output = New-object PsObject
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Server" -Value $tomcatserver
Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
     Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $tomcatserver ($ip) </td>"
     #Memory
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_Used" -Value $memory.total
    $memorytotal = $memory.total
    $memorytotal = $memorytotal/1MB
    $memorytotal = $memorytotal.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memorytotal MB</td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_free" -Value $memory.free
    $memoryfree = $memory.free
    $memoryfree = $memoryfree/1MB
    $memoryfree = $memoryfree.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryfree MB</td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_Max" -Value $memory.max
    $memorymax = $memory.max
    $memorymax = $memorymax/1MB
    $memorymax = $memorymax.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memorymax MB</td>"
    #Name:PS Eden Space Type:Heap memory Initial:1210056704 Committed:1155530752 Maximum:1168113664 Used:1027265568 

    $memoryEdenUsed = $MemoryEden.usageUsed
    $memoryOldGenUsed = $MemoryOldGen.usageUsed
    $memorySurvivorUsed = $MemorySurvivor.usageUsed
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryEdenUsed + $memoryOldGenUsed + $memorySurvivorUsed
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryHeapUsed/1MB
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryHeapUsed.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryHeapUsed MB</td>"

    $memoryEdenMax = $MemoryEden.usageMax
    $memoryOldGenMax = $MemoryOldGen.usageMax
    $memorySurvivorMax = $MemorySurvivor.usageMax
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryEdenMax + $memoryOldGenMax + $memorySurvivorMax
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryHeapMax/1MB
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryHeapMax.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryHeapMax MB</td>"
    $PercentUsed = ($memoryHeapUsed / $memoryHeapMax)*100
    $PercentUsed = [Math]::Round($PercentUsed, 0)
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $PercentUsed %</td>"
     #threads
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Current_Threads_busy" -Value $threads.currentThreadsBusy
    $threadscurrentThreadsBusy = $threads.currentThreadsBusy
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $threadscurrentThreadsBusy </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Current_Thread_Count" -Value $threads.currentThreadCount
    $threadscurrentThreadCount = $threads.currentThreadCount
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $threadscurrentThreadCount </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Max_Threads" -Value $threads.MaxThreads
    $threadsMaxThreads = $threads.MaxThreads
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $threadsMaxThreads </td>"
     #requestInfo
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Request_Max_ProcessingTime_ms" -Value $requestInfo.maxTime
    $requestInfomaxTime = $requestInfo.maxTime
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $requestInfomaxTime </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Request_Count" -Value $requestInfo.requestcount
    $requestInforequestcount = $requestInfo.requestcount
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $requestInforequestcount </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "ProcessingTime_total_s" -Value $requestInfo.processingTime
    $requestInfoprocessingTime = $requestInfo.processingTime
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $requestInfoprocessingTime </td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"

     #Return $output
}
```

The part that is giving me a hard time is:

```
#Name:PS Eden Space Type:Heap memory Initial:1210056704 Committed:1155530752 Maximum:1168113664 Used:1027265568 

    $memoryEdenUsed = $MemoryEden.usageUsed
    $memoryOldGenUsed = $MemoryOldGen.usageUsed
    $memorySurvivorUsed = $MemorySurvivor.usageUsed
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryEdenUsed + $memoryOldGenUsed + $memorySurvivorUsed
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryHeapUsed/1MB
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryHeapUsed.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryHeapUsed MB</td>"

    $memoryEdenMax = $MemoryEden.usageMax
    $memoryOldGenMax = $MemoryOldGen.usageMax
    $memorySurvivorMax = $MemorySurvivor.usageMax
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryEdenMax + $memoryOldGenMax + $memorySurvivorMax
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryHeapMax/1MB
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryHeapMax.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryHeapMax MB</td>"
    $PercentUsed = ($memoryHeapUsed / $memoryHeapMax)*100
    $PercentUsed = [Math]::Round($PercentUsed, 0)
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $PercentUsed %</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out..

Reading.

https://smarttechie.org/2016/08/15/understanding-the-java-memory-model-and-the-garbage-collection/

Heap Memory: JVM uses this memory to store the objects. This memory in turn split into two different areas called “Young Generation Space” and “Tenured Space“.

Young Generation: The Young Generation or the New Space is divided into two portions called “Eden Space” and “Survivor Space“.

Eden Space:When we create an object, the memory will be allocated from Eden Space.

Reading this, we need to remove:
Survivor and old
And we see favorable results.

Here is the finalized code:

```
function Get-TomcatStatus{
     param(
     $fileName,
         $tomcatserver ,
         $tomcatport = 80,
         $tomcatuser = "login",
         $tomcatpassword = "password"
     )
     # https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3iced0/gettomcat_status/
     #Get Credentials into the right format
     $tomcatpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $tomcatpassword -asplaintext -force
     $cred = New-object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ($tomcatuser,$tomcatpassword)

     #Invoke the restinterface 
     Write-Host http://$tomcatserver`:$tomcatport/manager/status?XML=true
     $TomcatStats = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://$tomcatserver`:$tomcatport/manager/status?XML=true -Credential $cred

     # <threadInfo  maxThreads="150" currentThreadCount="25" currentThreadsBusy="1" />
     $threads = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("threadInfo") | ? {$_.currentThreadCount -ne 0}

     $Memory = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memory") 

     # <memorypool name='PS Eden Space' type='Heap memory' usageInit='1210056704' usageCommitted='1155530752' usageMax='1168113664' usageUsed='1027265568'/>
     $MemoryEden = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memorypool") | ? {$_.name -eq "PS Eden Space"}
     #$MemoryOldGen = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memorypool") | ? {$_.name -eq "PS Old Gen"}
     #$MemorySurvivor = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memorypool") | ? {$_.name -eq "PS Survivor Space"}

     # <requestInfo  maxTime="6302" processingTime="32729" requestCount="260" errorCount="215" bytesReceived="61985" bytesSent="162507" />
     $requestInfo = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("requestInfo") | ? {$_.bytessent -ne 0}

     #Populate output object
     #$Output = New-object PsObject
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Server" -Value $tomcatserver
    Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
     Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $tomcatserver ($ip) </td>"
     #Memory
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_Used" -Value $memory.total
    $memorytotal = $memory.total
    $memorytotal = $memorytotal/1MB
    $memorytotal = $memorytotal.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memorytotal MB</td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_free" -Value $memory.free
    $memoryfree = $memory.free
    $memoryfree = $memoryfree/1MB
    $memoryfree = $memoryfree.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryfree MB</td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_Max" -Value $memory.max
    $memorymax = $memory.max
    $memorymax = $memorymax/1MB
    $memorymax = $memorymax.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memorymax MB</td>"
    #Name:PS Eden Space Type:Heap memory Initial:1210056704 Committed:1155530752 Maximum:1168113664 Used:1027265568 

    $memoryEdenUsed = $MemoryEden.usageUsed
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryEdenUsed
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryHeapUsed/1MB
    $memoryHeapUsed = $memoryHeapUsed.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryHeapUsed MB</td>"

    $memoryEdenMax = $MemoryEden.usageMax
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryEdenMax
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryHeapMax/1MB
    $memoryHeapMax = $memoryHeapMax.ToString("00.00")
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $memoryHeapMax MB</td>"
    $PercentUsed = ($memoryHeapUsed / $memoryHeapMax)*100
    $PercentUsed = [Math]::Round($PercentUsed, 0)
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $PercentUsed %</td>"
     #threads
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Current_Threads_busy" -Value $threads.currentThreadsBusy
    $threadscurrentThreadsBusy = $threads.currentThreadsBusy
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $threadscurrentThreadsBusy </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Current_Thread_Count" -Value $threads.currentThreadCount
    $threadscurrentThreadCount = $threads.currentThreadCount
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $threadscurrentThreadCount </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Max_Threads" -Value $threads.MaxThreads
    $threadsMaxThreads = $threads.MaxThreads
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $threadsMaxThreads </td>"
     #requestInfo
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Request_Max_ProcessingTime_ms" -Value $requestInfo.maxTime
    $requestInfomaxTime = $requestInfo.maxTime
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $requestInfomaxTime </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Request_Count" -Value $requestInfo.requestcount
    $requestInforequestcount = $requestInfo.requestcount
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $requestInforequestcount </td>"
     #$output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "ProcessingTime_total_s" -Value $requestInfo.processingTime
    $requestInfoprocessingTime = $requestInfo.processingTime
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $requestInfoprocessingTime </td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"

     #Return $output
}
```